# how to change int value based on tuple count

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to write different file names or perform similar function based on values of a tuple count.

example

```
a= ('hello','my','friend')
b = len(a)  ## which is 3
a[0] ## which is 'hello'
a[1] ## which is 'my' and so on
```

But after reading the len of a I will know it is 3. What I want to do then is to write a file based on the length of a starting from 0 to 2. In other word read the len of a and then do the following.

```
file = open('0.txt','w')
file.write("whatever")
file.close()

file = open('1','w')
file.write("whatever")
file.close()

file = open('2','w')
file.write("whatever")
file.close()
```

So that I can use the same code for a list of 10 or 100 tuples it will automatically adjust depending on the value read from len(a).

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`range()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range) or [`xrange()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#xrange) functions to generate a sequence of integer values based on the tuple length:

```
for i in xrange(len(a)):
    filename = '{}.txt'.format(i)
```

This will loop 3 times, generating the numbers `0`, `1` and `2`, which can then be used to generate filenames, etc.

`xrange()` generates numbers on demand, `range()` generates a list with the numbers first; the former is more memory efficient, the latter gives you a list for further manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

xrange() will create an iterator from 0 to whatever number you are looking for.

You can use any type of string formatting to create the unique file name.

```
for i in xrange(0,len(a)):
    file = open("file_%d.txt" % i, 'w')
    file.write("whatever")
    file.close()
```

EDIT: used len(a) to make the example clearer like suggested

Comment: Thank you everyone for reply. I will try xrange and revert soonest.. Thx again

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned a list `a`, you might be interested in following approach:

```
a = ('hello', 'my', 'friend')
for i, value in enumerate(a):
   # here i stands for index
   # value for tuple value of this index, a[i]
   print i, value
```

outputs

```
0 hello
1 my
2 friend
```